# Get the refund reason in Woocommerce customer refunded order notification

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

I would like to display the refund reason on the refund email in woocommerce. I'm editing directly in customer-refunded-order.php which is copied in my child theme.

I see that in the crud object for order that I could get to the refund_reson from there

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Order-and-Order-Line-Item-Data#refund

```php
<?php printf( __( '%s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_refund_reason() ); ?>
```

I would simply like to see the refund reason being displayed in the email,but this code breaks the process (when I start a refund the page loads forever and doesn't refresh, as it gets stuck in the email creation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

First you don't need `__( '%s', 'woocommerce' )` as there is nothing to translate, so you don't need `printf()` function either.

Since WooCommerce 3, the `WC_Order_Refund` method [`get_refund_reason()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-order-refund.php#L218-L228) is deprecated and replaced by [`get_reason()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-order-refund.php#L81-L90) method.

It doesn't work because you need to get the refunded orders (they can be many for an order) from the `WC_Order` Object, using the method `get_refunds()`…

Try the following instead:

```
<?php 
// Get the Order refunds (array of refunds)
$order_refunds = $order->get_refunds();

// Loop through refunded orders for the current WC_Order object
foreach( $order_refunds as $order_refund ){
    // To be sure we check if that method exist and that is not empty
    if( method_exists( $order_refund, 'get_reason' ) && $order_refund->get_reason() ) {
        echo '<p>' . esc_html( $order_refund->get_reason() ) . '</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

It should work.